# Users are getting logged out

Tags: redirect, drupal, rules

I have a Drupal commerce install, with commerce entity membership among other modules. Everything is working fine from my computer, I tested with all kinds of users and roles, but my client (in Belgium) and his new users experience many issues, they get logged out when accessing views where I restricted access to specific roles. The site is in production, customers are coming, they join as members but this issue will cause troubles I fear. I used .htaccess to redirect www to domain, again on my home computers and mobile phone it's working fine... I don't know what to do. Can someone help ?
Edit : I created a rule to redirect users on first login (one-time-login link provided in welcome email) to the account edit page

```
{ "rules_first_time_login" : {    "LABEL" : "first time login",    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",    "WEIGHT" : "0",    "OWNER" : "rules",    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],    "ON" : { "user_login" : [] },    "IF" : [ { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:last-access" ] } } ],    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "user\/[account:uid]\/edit" } } ]  } }
```

Another rule is triggered for these users to be redirected to members' area

```
{ "rules_redirect_user_on_password_change" : {    "LABEL" : "Redirect user on password change",    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",    "OWNER" : "rules",    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],    "ON" : { "user_update" : [] },    "IF" : [
     { "NOT data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "account:last-login" ] } },
     { "user_has_role" : {
         "account" : [ "account" ],
         "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4", "5" : "5" } },
         "operation" : "OR"
       }
     }    ],    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "[site:url]members" } } ]  } }
```

A third rule for normal users after login

```
{ "rules_redirect_to_members" : {    "LABEL" : "redirect to members",    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",    "WEIGHT" : "1",    "OWNER" : "rules",    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],    "ON" : { "user_login" : [] },    "IF" : [
     { "user_has_role" : {
         "account" : [ "account" ],
         "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4", "5" : "5" } },
         "operation" : "OR"
       }
     },
     { "NOT text_matches" : { "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ], "match" : "user\/reset" } }    ],    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "[site:url]members" } } ]  } }
```

Do you see any misconfiguration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers, as Firefox for example are treating subdomains as www as totally different domains. So, if user logs in at www.domain.com and you re-direct it to domain.com it will not be logged in any more on some browsers. Try it your self with Firefox - I don't think it's location, but browser related.

Comment: Yes you are right, but everything is ok about this. As everything is ok on my computer (tested with 5 different browsers) and my mobile android, I suspect it is related to cookies management which must not be correct on some browsers' old version (I saw there were issues like mine on old Safari).
I cannot see what I can do about this, I tried to disable cache for anonymous users. The problem is I cannot test this myself...